# How to modify Team Foundation Server reports to exclude weekends?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, report

I would like to modify the Team Foundation Server built-in MS Agile template reports to exclude weekends.

For example, here is the dsWorkItemHistory dataset for the Remaining Work report:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Date Key] AS
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.UniqueName

SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[Date Key],
    [Measures].[Cumulative Count]
  } ON COLUMNS,
  (
    [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State],
    (StrToMember(@StartDateParam):StrToMember(@EndDateParam))
  )
  ON ROWS
FROM [Team System]
WHERE
(
  STRTOMEMBER("[Team Project].[Team Project].["+@Project+"]"),
  STRTOSET(@IterationParam),
  STRTOSET(@AreaParam),
  STRTOSET(@WorkItemTypeParam)
)
```

I am totally unfamiliar with MDX. Any pointers toward customizing the data returned to exclude weekends is appreciated.

Comment: In your title, you want to exclude weekends, but in your post, you ask about excluding weekdays...you might want to clarify which is correct.

Comment: Oops, fixed. *weekends* are what I want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datepart function with the dw part to exclude Saturday and Sunday.

SYNTAX: `DATEPART ( datepart , date )`

in this case datepart = dw or weekday,
and date is the date field in your query.

Comment: Where exactly would this fit into the query in the question?